# Vue JS. Insert an item at random position inside a Vue component

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am working a project using Laravel and currently building a feature using Vue JS in my home page where I want to put an "Advertisement" at random position within the list.
Right now, I have setup a vue component  called "panel" which is then populated using the following template,

```
<template id="places-template">
    <div v-for="item in items">
          <div class="item">
             ...
          </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</template>
```

and this is how it looks on my javascript (this is the simplified version),

```
Vue.component('panel', {
    template: '#places-template',

    data() {
      return {
        places: [],
      }
    },

    created() {
      this.getPlaces("{{ route('user::get-places') }}");
    },

    methods: {
      getPlaces(url) {
        this.$http.get(url).then((response) => {
         this.places.push(response.data);
        });
      },
    }
  });
```

Right now everything works well and the requested server data are being displayed. But my problem is, I can't  insert new item between those elements already displayed. When I try to do $('.item').length returns 0 so apparently, jquery doesn't seem to see those elements in the DOM. What I plan to do is get the total length of the items already displayed and calculate a random digit which starts with 0 and ends with the total length of the item and from there insert a new item using $('.item').eq(randomDigit).after($(new-item));.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid using jQuery to manipulate the dom when you are using Vue.  Since Vue updates the dom when data changes, it may affect the element you inserted. It's better to let Vue handle the dom and you just deal with the data.  This code would insert an item into the array at a random position:

```
this.places.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*this.places.length), 0, foo);
```

You'll need to adjust your template to handle ads.

Comment: This works really well! So I just need to insert the append the new item to the array and not directly adding to the DOM. Thanks Jeff!